# How to scroll up with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollview

I tried everything, and i can't write the good Jquery code to make my body scrolls up.
This is my JS :

`$("body").animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 9000);
        $(this).fadeOut(fast);`

And it makes the body scroll down when user click on a specific div, then i want to reverse this function to make the body scrolls up.. any idea ?

Answer (score 13):

You need to supply a `0` as the argument to `scrollTop` if you want it to scroll upwards.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // scroll down
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 9000);                  

    /scroll back up
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 9000);                  
});
```

As you can see in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you need to provide a CSS property and a value as the first param to `animate()`. Since `scrollTop` ([doc of `scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), which returns the current value) is the vertical scroll bar and you want to scroll to the top, you need `0` there to go upwards.

Check this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vKWY/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks ! i think you get me out of problems ! I'll try and I'll tell you.

Comment: @LukyVj so did this help you?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 9000);
```

Comment: Try `scrollTop: $(document).height()`